# Alignment of radio button and drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fozW.png)I have to create "View" and "Update" radio buttons with a dropdown below each one. To do this, I've written the following code:

```html
<div class="pageHead" align="center">
  Auto Loan Basis Point (Bps) Adjustments by State
</div> <br><br>
<input type='radio' id='byState' ; style="margin-left:180px" ; value='View' name='byState'>View by Student's unique identity number
<input type='radio' id='byClub' ; style="margin-left:80px" ; value='Update' name='byClub'>Update by Student's identity number

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="width:200px;text-align: left; display: inline;">
        <select id="Select" ;>
          <option value="dropdown">Select</option>
          <option value="TN">Test1</option>
          <option value="IN">test2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, I'm unable to place the drop-down menu below radio buttons; this is what I get instead:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fozW.png)

Comment: Add your code here instead of image

Comment: I dont want to use table but want to align the dropdown exactly below my radio button, how do i achieve ? I just tried adding table for alignment but doesnt work, not sure of the approach since I'm new to this

Comment: @shwetha Check my answer. Tables do work. You just need to know how to manipulate them

Comment: @Alex tables should never be used for layout (unless it is an email template)

Comment: Why so? This is interesting @Pete

Comment: Semantics and accessibility and seo @Alex

Comment: Code looks kind of copy/pasted have a look at [HTML Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and you wont have to ask for minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Using CSS:**

---

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container,
.radio-buttons,
.radio-buttons>span,
.dropdowns {
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="pageHead" align="center">
  Auto Loan Basis Point (Bps) Adjustments by State
</div> <br><br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="radio-buttons">
    <div class="cell">
      <input type='radio' id='byState' value='View' name='byState'>View by Student's unique identity number
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <input type='radio' id='byClub' value='Update' name='byClub'>Update by Student's identity number </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdowns">
    <div class="cell">
      <select id="Select">
        <option value="dropdown">Select</option>
        <option value="TN">Test1</option>
        <option value="IN">test2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <select id="Select">
        <option value="dropdown">Select</option>
        <option value="TN">Test1</option>
        <option value="IN">test2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using Tables:**

---

You can use a table to align items together like so:

---

```css
td {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageHead" align="center">Auto Loan Basis Point (Bps) Adjustments by State</div> <br><br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' id='byState' value='View' name='byState'>View by Student's unique identity number
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='radio' id='byClub' value='Update' name='byClub'>Update by Student's identity number
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select id="Select">
          <option value="dropdown"> Select</option>
          <option value="TN">Test1</option>
          <option value="IN">test2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <select id="Select">
          <option value="dropdown"> Select</option>
          <option value="TN">Test1</option>
          <option value="IN">test2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I dont want to see the border and table , I just need 2 radio buttons and 2 dropdowns one above another.

Comment: I have updated my image, can u please refer to that, i dont want to see the table and the font also should match

Comment: @shwetha It's your job to fix the font and all the small bits, You asked to align them, I did, currently working on a tabless version.

Comment: @shwetha Edited. Have a look.

Comment: I am still not getting dropdowns  below radio button, it is placed in the center